# Activation record for main()

Tags: c++, c, function, stack, reverse-engineering

I am new to reversing. My apologies if question sounds to beginer-ish :) I have created simple code in Visual Studio C++ 2010 on XP SP3:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I open it in Olly it shows the following state of the stack with execution paused:

```
0012FFC4   7C817077  RETURN to kernel32.7C817077
0012FFC8   7C910228  ntdll.7C910228
0012FFCC   FFFFFFFF
0012FFD0   7FFD5000
0012FFD4   80544CFD
0012FFD8   0012FFC8
0012FFDC   82537DA8
0012FFE0   FFFFFFFF  End of SEH chain
0012FFE4   7C839AD8  SE handler
0012FFE8   7C817080  kernel32.7C817080
0012FFEC   00000000
0012FFF0   00000000
0012FFF4   00000000
0012FFF8   004012A0  Reversin.<ModuleEntryPoint>
0012FFFC   00000000
```

I can see end of SEH chain and SE handler the rest of it just doesn't make sense to me. I have found the following stack layout for the functions with exception handler installed:

```
Function_Local_Variables
Exception_Registration_Record
Exception_Handler
Callers_EBP
Return_Address_in_Caller
Function_Arguments
```

It does not seem to apply in my case. I need help trying to understand what's been stored in stack please.

Thank you.

Comment: What's "olly"? And exactly what are you doing or trying to find out? Please post a new more concrete question.

Comment: I would suggest perhaps that whatever applies for a normal function may not necessarily apply to main(); some of that is probably determined by the OS.  Beyond that, if the source is not available it is probably because the author wants it that way, and that should be respected, especially if the EULA expressly prohibits reverse engineering..

Comment: Olly is Olly Debugger. And i'm trying to look at my own code. I am trying to figure out why C++ compiler creates this stack records for main() just for educational purposes. I am not reversing anything that is prohibited, as it is indicated in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're trying to learn the stack convention by looking at hex in Olly, you should consider which stack convention your code is following.  By default, most C++ code follows the __cdecl convention.  Check out this link: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#cdecl